# for loops for string containing datetime() objects

Tags: python

here is a small code

```
ds = datetime.datetime.now()
de = ds + datetime.timedelta(days=99)
fd = list(rrule(DAILY, byweekday=(SA,SU), dtstart=ds, until=de))
for x in fd:
    print fd[x-1]
```

it should give me a list of datetime() objects. but it doesn't. here is the error method i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    int(fd[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: @Amber: I had to look it up, it looks like it's a part of [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subtract the `int` `1` from a `datetime.datetime` object.

`x` is a item from the `list` of `datetime.datetime` objects called `fd`, not an index.

Where you have:

```
for x in fd:
    print fd[x-1]
```

You want:

```
for x in fd:
    print x
```

This will give you a list of c. 29 items (depending on when you run it, naturally):

```
2012-01-29 19:47:23
2012-02-04 19:47:23
2012-02-05 19:47:23
2012-02-11 19:47:23
2012-02-12 19:47:23
[...]
2012-04-22 19:47:23
2012-04-28 19:47:23
2012-04-29 19:47:23
2012-05-05 19:47:23
2012-05-06 19:47:23
```

Comment: thankyou, this was helpful. but i solved my problem the other way. here is what i did. `for x in range(0,len(fd(x)):` .. `print fd(x)` .. and it gave me what i wanted . thanks for the help.

Comment: @mouse: `for x in range(0,len(fd)):` is not Pythonic. And `print fd(x)` is invalid. What was wrong with what I put in my answer?

Comment: sorry .. it was fd[x]. there was nothing wrong your solution. i needed x to be an integer, because i was dealing with multiple array.

Comment: @mouse: If you're using an `int` index to iterate over a `list`, the chances are you're not doing it right!

Answer (score 1):

`fd` is a list of `datetime` objects. `for x in fd` gives you all the objects in `fd`, not the index in `fd`. Looks like you need to do one of the followings:

```
for x in fd:
    print x  # not fd[x - 1]
```

Or

```
for x in range(len(fd)):
    print fd[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

- `fd` is a list of `datetime` objects.
- `fd[0]` is a `datetime` object.
- `int(fd[0])` raises a

  ```
  TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
  ```

  since you can't apply `int` to a datetime object; as the error says,
  `int` converts `str` or `ints` only to `ints`
- `fd[x]` raises a

  ```
  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not datetime.datetime
  ```

  since `x` itself is a `datetime` object, and is not a valid index for
  the list `fd`.
- `fd[x-1]` raises a

  ```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
  ```

  since `x` is a datetime object and you can't subtract an int from a
  datetime object.

If you describe what it is you are trying to print, we might be able to suggest what code produces it.

Comment: this is what i did to solve my problem `for x in range(0,len(fd):` .. i was trying to print a list of dates that falls on saturday and sunday between these particular dates. thanks